# SSLv3 Connection doesn't work

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have a problem trying to connect to a server. I have done a lot of examples, but didn't get a connection. The site is https://sikuani.udea.edu.co:4443 and it has a certificate (according to Chrome it is version 3).

I have a basic program to do this, but it always fail with these 2 errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

OR

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: close_notify
```

This is my code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        String httpsURL = "https://sikuani.udea.edu.co:4443";
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }   

        in.close();
    }   
}
```

I've searched on google, here, java's foros but I haven't found a solution (some foros say that is a Java error, other ones that using SSLv3 params is enough and other ones that creating a trusStore will work).

I think the close solution is using a trustStore and certificate, but I don't know how to set correct params to get this work.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

This is my output using System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake");:

```
// A lot of certificates are loaded...
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1413064824 bytes = { 174, 241, 202, 226, 44, 117, 251, 126, 253, 137, 159, 14, 36, 19, 204, 203, 101, 47, 192, 51, 106, 143, 205, 111, 4, 139, 102, 89 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=sikuani.udea.edu.co]
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 177
main, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, close_notify
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: close_notify
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: close_notify
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1991)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at Test.main(Test.java:44)
```

If I get rid of the line setting the protocol to SSLv3, I have this:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 235
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, unexpected_message main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message –
```

Comment: Might it be that the problem is on server side?
If you try to connect to `https://www.google.com/` everything works OK.

Comment: But server is working, if I try the same URL on browser, it works OK.

Comment: Post the stuff printed by `jqvax.net.debug=ssl,handshake"`. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you should use then:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        try{
            String httpsURL = "https://sikuani.udea.edu.co:4443";
            URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
            InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }   

            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    } 
}
```

Leave the debug on so you can see what is happening.
I changed the code as per the comments I got back. There was no nee to add the lines I added. Also, you can use `HttpURLConnection` instead of `HttpsURLConnection` since it extends it. Adding 'SSLv2Hello' fixes the problem.

I think this should work - try it out now.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I don't have Eclipse, I'm working over console, and I have added these 2 lines and I have this error now:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

Comment: Alvin, I've copied your code, but it still doesn't work (It throw me the same error). I'm using jdk-1.8.0_20.jdk. I don't know if it is relevant. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed JDK1.8.0_20 and the code works with that. Did you rerun "javac Test.java" and then "java Test"?

Comment: Never ignore exceptions. There's an unused import. You haven't need to set `java.protocol.handler.pkgs`, or add the Sun SSL provider, for ten years. You haven't explained why this is the code he must use. -1

Comment: Hi Alvin, I did the javac and java but the error is the same, Java can't do the cast.

Comment: @EJP - you were right, those lines are old and not needed anymore. I didn't find this out until I looked it up. I was only trying to get this person up and running as quickly as possible, and looked at someone else's example.

Comment: Code is modified - try it out again. If you get errors, can you post the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the line that sets the SSLv3 protocol. You don't need it. X509 version 3 isn't the same as SSLv3.

Comment: Hi EJP, if I get rid of the line, I have this:

`main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 235
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unexpected_message
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message`

Comment: Curious. If I remove it the alert I get is `illegal_parameter.` If I set it to `TLSv1` it is `unexpected_message.` If I set it to `SSLv3` it is `close_notify.`

Comment: @EJP, this should be addressed by the `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");` that I added to my code sample. I was seeing similar error messages.

Comment: @AlvinBunk OK well it should be at least `"TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello"`.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem, so do you think is a problem about server? or about the ignored ciphers? or about Java config? thank you for your help.

Comment: What errors do you see from the debug, can you post them?

Comment: Thank you a lot EJP, and Alvin, it works. That is nice, and a little explanation, why is this working? I have been reading, and my conclusion is that the protocol is old, am I right? Again thank you for your help.

Comment: Which code did you use? Did you use mine? If so, select it as the answer. I believe the main problem was the missing "SSLv2Hello" if that is the case.